# how do I get rid of the tuple in a dataframe subgroup?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to rescale values of grouped rows into percentages of their total through a series of two group statements as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'name': 'A', 'x':1, 'y':1},{'name': 'B', 'x':2, 'y':4},{'name': 'A', 'x':3, 'y':2}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.groupby(['name','y']).size().groupby(level=0).apply(
    lambda x: 100 * x / x.sum()
).to_frame().unstack()
```

I get the following output:

```
    0
y   1       2       4
name            
A   50.0    50.0    NaN
B   NaN     NaN     100.0
```

This is the output I am looking for, but... with that additional 0 dimension added to the column headers... what causes that and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `groupby(level=0)` portion is the cause of the new 0 level in your output. This seems to accomplish the same, without the 0 level and no lambda. I believe I captured your overall intent.

```py
df.groupby(['name','y']).size().div(df.groupby('name')['y'].count()).unstack(level=-1) * 100
```

Results in:

```
y        1     2      4
name                   
A     50.0  50.0    NaN
B      NaN   NaN  100.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that indeed does what I needed and solves the problem!

Comment: Awesome! And if I'm not mistaken, your name is Peter too, so double bonus.